# Can not return array with strings from kernel space to user space linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I have this code in kernel space, which invokes when program from user space read file /dev/myprogram:

```
  char **array = kmalloc(5, GFP_KERNEL);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      array[i] = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL);
  }

  strcpy(array[0], "aaa");
  strcpy(array[1], "fooyes");
  strcpy(array[2], "bbdfdfb");
  strcpy(array[3], "ccc1234");
  strcpy(array[4], "csddbbbbbcc");

  copy_to_user(buffer, array, 500);
```

And this code in user space, which has to get list from kernel space:

```
 #define BUFFER_LENGTH 500
    char** receive;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
       int fd;
       fd = open("/dev/myprogram", O_RDWR);
        receive = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
           receive[i] = (char *)malloc(100+1);
        }
        read(fd, receive, BUFFER_LENGTH);
       for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
         printf("The received message is : [%s] \n", receive[i]);
       }
```

When I am trying to get this array of strings I get segmentation fault in kernel and nothing is displayed. Please, help me to find the way to pass the whole list. Is there better way to do this ?

Comment: You’re only copying the pointers and trying to get 500 bytes whereas you only allocate 5 bytes. This isn’t enough for even one pointer in a 64bit system and for one in a 32bit system. This will surely crash because you’re going out of bounds in multiple places.

Comment: hey, thanks for answer. Can you help me to fix this ? How to copy all data ?

Comment: Allocate enough memory for the whole data as one memory area, concatenate the strings into it, copy it out, kfree it

Comment: you mean, that I have to use char* Data instead of char** ?  and push all data to char* Data and pass it  using copy_to_user function ?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. This also depends on the actual other code you’ve written. If it’s a char device there should be a read method where you copy suitable part out etc. So without seeing the whole device code can’t say exactly.

Comment: but how can I separate different strings, if they are stored in one symbols array char* Data ? Do I have to use some separator ? for example, I have 4 words: "string1", "string2", "str3", "str_4"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159840/discussion-between-vcvv-and-sami-kuhmonen).

Comment: @Vcvv: null-byte could be reliable separator between strings: 's', 't', 'r', '1', '\0', 's', 't', 'r', '2', '\0'.

Comment: This is a c language problem, not a kernel problem.